# Visual Studio 2013 Javascript doesn't recognize '<%= %>'?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

When I am upgrading from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2013. The code in Javascript in VS 2010 shown red text in between ' ' and the website is working fine,

```
id = '<%= Company.NEAt.GetUserID().ToString() %>';
```

But in VS 2013, it doesn't show red text in between ' ' and I got error on website saying,

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: Have you already work through this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Most probably `Company.NEAt.GetUserID()` gets resolved to `NULL` ??

Comment: How does it become null when I am only upgrading to 2013? I didn't change any code at all and it work fine in 2010

Comment: which .NET framework are you targeting? did it change when you upgraded to 2013?

Comment: In VS 2010, I am targeting .NET Framework 4. In VS 2013, I am targeting the same .NET Framework 4. It didn't change it to higher or lower version of Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that I wasn't expecting.

All I had to do is disable anonymous Authentication in IIS and it worked fine. It because this code is waiting to get window authentication, not anonymous.